# But for your help, no boys(boy?) would have succeeded in a competition like this

Tags: singular-vs-plural, nouns

> But for your help, no boys(boy?) would have succeeded in a competition like this.

I don't know why but boy sounds better to my ears here perhaps because of no one , no body. Is it fine to use boy**s** here ?

Comment: Was it a boys only competition? And if there was one winner, only one boy won, so one boy succeeded. The question is not very clear. Aside, we say **nobody** not **no body**, however **no one** is correct not **noone**.

Comment: @WeatherVane - I agree it's an unclear question. I don't agree that "only one boy one, so one boy succeeded" (it could be a team competition, or a meet with several events where several boys are bringing home medals.

Comment: @J.R. you missed the ***if*** one winner. Unclear question still.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Nope, I didn't miss the conditional. My point is that, even if there is only one winner, more than one can succeed. Success can be measured in many ways – particularly in youth events.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think it can be implied from the sentence in question that the event was a boys only competition.. I don't know if there was one winner or many, I am just asking is using boys grammatical correct ?

Answer (score 1):

I read it, "If not for your help, nobody would have won." I made a couple of summarizations that result in a clearer, more concise, less ambiguous sentence. I also left gender out of it, which removed the singular/plural "problem" from the sentence.